# Adjective noun phrase

Tags: phrases, nouns

We have accepted adjective-noun phrases in English, such as "small talk" and "big business."  I ran across this sentence in a local paper last week:

Johnson said,"There's a lot more hope.  And there's a lot more less uncertainty."

It seems the speaker was trying to create a new adjective-noun phrase here by saying "more less uncertainty," with "less uncertainty" being his new adjective-noun phrase.

Is there a grammatical name for accepted adjective-noun phrases in English?

Thanks.

Addition--

I think I was imprecise when I used the word "accepted" in conjunction with noun-adjective phrases. I meant to say something like "standardized" or "idiomatic," like "boom town" or "dirty business," that is, adjective-noun phrases that most native speakers understand as having a shared meaning among users of English.

I certainly agree that litotes can take the form of adjective-noun understatement, but I'm still wondering if there is a grammatical name for an adjective-noun pair when the combination has a set, understood meaning, like "big ask" (which seems to have an understood meaning in the private equity and capital markets in the US).

Comment: Maybe Boris was (once again) tripping over his tongue...?

Comment: @Cascabel The source is not Boris Johnson, but a local restaurant owner: https://www.hometownsource.com/sun_current/community/edina-restaurants-reopen-after-holiday-shutdowns/article_f3281da6-6d57-11eb-ab2e-1b86b4e696a4.html

Comment: It was some American person called Johnson. Google leads me to believe it is someone called Ken Johnson who owns 3 restaurants in Edina, Minnesota, USA. I can think of two possibilities: 1. He actually said that, and the reporter just reproduced the error 2. The local reporter made a typing error. Note: Don't try that link if you live in Europe. The site says that due to us having GDPR, it won't let us look at it.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I read about the introduction of GDPR, but never thought it might block info between us and EU. Maybe a meta issue?

Comment: @Cascabel - Some American web sites refuse to allow users with European internet addresses to view their content. They may think GDPR applies to them simply because Europeans view their content (it doesn't). Another reason is that GDPR _does_ apply to companies outside Europe that gather information about users for certain purposes, including tracking and targeted marketing, and that company may be doing that to its users.

Comment: So 'one person said one thing once' now makes a pattern to accept or reject? Lord save me from all my verbal Oops, and don't cast them in concrete.

Comment: @YosefBaskin    ...seem to remember Anthony Burgess saying something similar about Göering  r.e. one of those god-awful speeches that served no other purpose than to glorify the regime with impossible comparatives. Gonna hafta blow the dust off a few volumes to find that.

Comment: @Cascabel - many US news websites block European IP addresses. [This 2018 Guardian story](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2018/may/25/gdpr-us-based-news-websites-eu-internet-users-la-times) is still true for many sites. Also [this Niemanlab story](https://www.niemanlab.org/2018/08/more-than-1000-u-s-news-sites-are-still-unavailable-in-europe-two-months-after-gdpr-took-effect/) is informative.

Comment: It's a hassle for US based people wanting to read US news while on vacation in Europe.

Comment: @Cascabel - the issue isn't GDPR 'blocking' Europeans from using US based sites; the issue is US web site owners choosing to block them because they either don't understand, or don't wish to comply or engage with, European law.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I just saw today on CNN that something related tangentially is causing blocking of news items on FB in Austalia and possible actions by Google...developing story.

Answer (score 1):

I am no native speaker but I don't see that as an approach to establish a new phrase and neither as a adjective-noun phrase. Instead the "more less" paradox is the unusual part of the sentence and therefore the construction to focus on (with *more* used as an adverb to describe the increased form of *less*). [*I really hope it is an adverb, it would be in German.*]
This could be either an accident (by Johnson OR the writer of the article) or meant as a word play by phrasing two opposing developments (increasing and decreasing) both the same way (as something increasing and the other thing increasing its decrease).
I don't know why he didn't say "more little" instead of "more less", with less already being the (grammatically) increased form of little. Maybe he wanted to emphasize the joke, while "more little hope" could have the bad connotation of *more hope, but but still being only little*.

However, I don't have the name for naturalized adjective-noun expressions.

Comment: I also read it as an accident. There may also be a conflict between parallelism (*more hope* sets up saying *more* again) and his wanting to say *uncertainty*, which makes sense in context with *less* than *more*.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin If there is a video of the interview/statement, maybe it would become obvious, if it was meant funny or if he stumbles.

Answer (score 0):

> We have accepted adjective-noun phrases in English, such as "small talk" and "big business."

The purpose of an adjective is to qualify a noun. All adjective + noun phrases are acceptable and always have been. Not all make sense, but nevertheless, they are acceptable.

> Johnson said,"There's a lot more hope. And there's a lot more less uncertainty."

I would call "**less uncertainty**" a noun phrase. Noun phrases are "acceptable": they can be coined at will.

**Less uncertainty** is an example (not particularly idiomatic) of litotes a rhetorical figure of speech in which an affirmative is expressed by the negative of the contrary; an instance of this. Examples of litotes are: ‘A citizen of no mean city’; ‘When no small tempest lay on us.’

Answer (score 0):

> And there's a lot more less uncertainty.

It's not standard English, and not an idiomatic expression. It sounds like some politician trying to weasel-word their statement to sound more positive when the actual prospect is quite bleak.

The last time I heard this phraseology used convincingly was :

["Less is More"](https://www.lexico.com/definition/less_is_more)

> Used to express the view that a minimalist approach to artistic or aesthetic matters is more effective.

Johnson seems to be stringing words together in an effort  to take advantage of associations...

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be an editing mistake. It could be a) a failed attempt to introduce the term 'more or less' or 2) a change of wording to include the word 'uncertainty' without correcting the preceding words i.e., either the word 'more' or the word 'less'should have been removed before print. I'd go for removing the word 'more' because the first part of the sentence was positive, while uncertain could be negative! Maybe more hope = less uncertainty